# Meshlights darker in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

It seems like the emission shader lights up other objects stronger in the preview render than in final renders.

[image: Preview Render Difference]

I'm using mesh lights in Blender 2.78. The error is reproducible by creating a plane with an emission shader and a subject with any kind of material, that's lit by the plane.

[image: Lamp Material]

As I didn't find any reports of this issue, I'm wondering if I'm the only one experiencing it, and if so, what settings might cause this.

[image]

---

EDIT:

After resetting the preferences in the `System` tab this is the render:
[image: Render After Adjusting Preferences]

It is a bit closer to the preview, but then I noticed that both of the lights are reflected two times. (Which was visible before, but I didn't realize it.)

I also tried to render with CPU, and the result was identical to the preview.

So it's definitely a problem with the GPU (Nvidia).
It's unlikely a driver problem since I noticed the problem some weeks ago.

Comment: hmm..here it looks the same. Try File->Load Factory settings. Maybe you have set something in the userpreferences or something..

Comment: Have you applied the scale to your mesh lights?

Comment: I did now, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Delagone's comment without success,

> Have you applied the scale to your mesh lights?

but later I could fix the problem by also applying Rotation and Location.

I don't know what the GPU thinks the lamps looked like, but without *all three* transformations applied, the rendered image was wrong in some way.